# How to disable AJAX in a Rails app using JQueryMobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, asset-pipeline

I've built a Rails 3 app and I'm trying to get it working with JQueryMobile. I've gone ahead and required `query_mobile_rails` and that works just fine, but I need to disable the AJAX loading as it seems to get in the way of many things. Looking at the [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2) docs, they recommend adding the following javascript after loading JQuery, but before loading JQueryMobile:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

I've been reading through the docs on the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care), but I cannot figure out how I can manage to get my code (the above) inserted after JQuery and before JQueryMobile. Where do I place such a .js file so that it will be loaded at the proper time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I got it. I created a file called `app/assets/app_lib.js` with the code above and then added a `require app_lib` between `require jquery` and `require query.mobile` in my `application.js` file.

Comment: @fwidtmann – what does _not working_ mean? Are you seeing errors? Can you share your code?